# Problems with the inverse of a banded matrix: not invertible?

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

I am creating with a software a banded matrix, which is also symmetric. In fact, its definition comes from an array, `Array[q]`, whose length is `n`, where I store my values.
Then to define my matrix I do the following:

`Matrix[i][j] = Array[abs[i-j]]`,

where `abs` indicates the absolute value. The result is, in the case of `n=8` for example,

```
{0.590818, 0.574632, 0.528687, 0.460129, 0.378821, 0.295026, 
   0.21735, 0.151471},
  {0.574632, 0.590818, 0.574632, 0.528687, 0.460129, 0.378821, 
   0.295026, 0.21735},
  {0.528687, 0.574632, 0.590818, 0.574632, 0.528687, 0.460129, 
   0.378821, 0.295026},
  {0.460129, 0.528687, 0.574632, 0.590818, 0.574632, 0.528687, 
   0.460129, 0.378821},
  {0.378821, 0.460129, 0.528687, 0.574632, 0.590818, 0.574632, 
   0.528687, 0.460129},
  {0.295026, 0.378821, 0.460129, 0.528687, 0.574632, 0.590818, 
   0.574632, 0.528687},
  {0.21735, 0.295026, 0.378821, 0.460129, 0.528687, 0.574632, 
   0.590818, 0.574632},
  {0.151471, 0.21735, 0.295026, 0.378821, 0.460129, 0.528687, 
   0.574632, 0.590818}
 }
```

Now the point is that I need to calculate the inverse of this matrix. As long as `n=8`, I manage to make the software do that, but as soon as I grow with the dimension, say `n=64` for example, I get the error that the matrix is badly conditioned, because the determinant is (almost) 0. In fact, if I calculate the determinant in the case `n=64`, I get that it is equal to

```
1.483771072856803*10^-498
```

My question is: why should such a banded matrix be singular? I cannot see an evident reason.

Comment: It seems to me that `Matrix[i][j]=Array[abs[i-j]]` defines a symmetric Toeplitz matrix instead of a general symmetric banded matrix.

Comment: A small comment: I don't know what software do you use but if it determines bad conditioning by looking at the value of the determinant, I would suggest replacing it by another software since determinant has no connection to the condition number whatsoever. For example, a diagonal $n\times n$ matrix $D:=\mathrm{diag}(0.1,\ldots,0.1)$ has determinant $10^{-n}$ (arbitrarily small for large $n$) but its spectral condition number is 1.